# Firebase detect deletion using observeEventType FIRDataEventTypeValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am observing using the FIRDataEventTypeValue, and according to the documentation a block will get triggered:

"Your block will be triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data changes."

I keep a local cache of the data in an NSMutatbleArray and when the event fires
I search the cache and if an entry is found, the data gets updated with new values.

And if the entry is not found in the cache, I add the data to the cache.

**But how do I take care of deletion?** I do not want to use a separate observer, or is this the only way.

```
[_myRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
    if (dict == (id)[NSNull null]) {
        [_cache removeAllObjects];
        [self dataEvent];
        return;
    }
   [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    // extract values from obj and store it in a cache
```

Answer (score 0):

The method **observeEventType:withBlock** will get called with **all** the data contained in the snapshot, so you can **"delete"** the data by rebuilding the entire cache, also no need to update the cache entries.

```
    [_myRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    [_cache removeAllObjects];

    NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
    if (dict == (id)[NSNull null]) {
        [self dataEvent];
        return;
    }

    [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    // process the dictionary and its values and store in the cache
```